# Telegram Bot custom keyboard in PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a Telegram Bot in PHP with a custom keyboard. The message is delivered, but the custom keyboard won't work. $keyb = array('keyboard' => array(array("A", "B"))); also no succes.

The [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method referrers to [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) for the object. Making an array for ReplyKeyboardMarkup doesn't work. Also tried to json_encode($keyb) but that's also not the solution.

I searched in GitHub for examples but I haven't found one where the custom keyboard is used. Telegram runs on iPhone and desktop, both up-to-date.

Sample code:

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage";

$keyb = array('ReplyKeyboardMarkup' => array('keyboard' => array(array("A", "B"))));
$content = array('chat_id' => <chat_id>, 'reply_markup' => $keyb, 'text' => "Test");

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($content));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  //fix http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The docs seem to indicate you need to provide the reply_markup parameter as a JSON serialised object... kinda stupid for a form POST endpoint:

```
$replyMarkup = array(
    'keyboard' => array(
        array("A", "B")
    )
);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);
$content = array(
    'chat_id' => <chat_id>,
    'reply_markup' => $encodedMarkup,
    'text' => "Test"
);
```

Does this one work?

Comment: No, doesn't work either.. Forgot to mention but tried that also

Comment: Seems this is the correct approach according to reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3bblz0/sendmessage_with_replykeyboardmarkup_problem May be worth dumping your post data and comparing. Goodluck.

Comment: Yes, this one works! I though I tried it all, but clearly this one I skipped. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, one has to include all the fields into the ReplyKeyboardMarkup object, not only `keyboard`.

Comment: @DeerHunter This is false, the rest of fields are optional.

Answer (score 17):

```
   $keyboard = array(array("[Destaques]","[Campinas e RMC]","[esportes]"));
   $resp = array("keyboard" => $keyboard,"resize_keyboard" => true,"one_time_keyboard" => true);
   $reply = json_encode($resp);
   $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=oi&reply_markup=".$reply;
    file_get_contents($url);
```

This code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyboard = [
            'keyboard' => [
                [
                    ['text' => 'hourly', 'callback_data' => 'Every hour'],
                    ['text' => 'daily', 'callback_data' => 'Every day'],
                    ['text' => 'weekly', 'callback_data' => 'Every week'],
                    ['text' => 'monthly', 'callback_data' => 'Every month'],
                    ['text' => 'yearly', 'callback_data' => 'Every year'],
                ]            ]
        ];
```

this works for me