# ReplyKeyboardMarkup doesn't work python?

Tags: python, arrays, telegram-bot

I wrote a telegram bot. All things went well and it worked well. But when I want to use `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` as it mentioned in its [document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup), it did not work! I mean the keyboard doesn't show up.

This  JSON object has a key `keyboard` and its value ,according to its doc, is:

> **type:** Array of Array of String.
>
> **description:** Array of button rows, each represented by an Array of Strings

This is my code for sending the request:

```
reply_markup = {'keyboard': [['1'],['2']], 'resize_keyboard': True, 'one_time_keyboard': True}
params = urllib.urlencode({
      'chat_id': str(chat_id),
      'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
      'reply_markup': reply_markup,
      'disable_web_page_preview': 'true',
      # 'reply_to_message_id': str(message_id),
})
resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', params).read()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to serialize reply_markup to JSON string separately, like in this answer [Telegram bot custom keyboard in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099087/telegram-bot-custom-keyboard-in-php)

Comment: Yes I realized it last night but I forgot to remove my question! +1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Because it still took me a bit of trial and error to get in right in Python even after reading the PHP answer linked to by Kostya, here is a the adapted Python code that works (you just need to add your bot's token and a chat ID to send the message to).

Note that I also had to update my Telegram client to the newest version (currently 3.1) to see the result.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json


TOKEN = "<your bot token>"
chat_id = <your chat id>


msg = "some string"
BASE_URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)

reply_markup = {'keyboard': [['1'],['2']], 'resize_keyboard': True, 'one_time_keyboard': True}
reply_markup = json.dumps(reply_markup)
params = urllib.urlencode({
      'chat_id': str(chat_id),
      'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
      'reply_markup': reply_markup,
      'disable_web_page_preview': 'true',
      # 'reply_to_message_id': str(message_id),
})
resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', params).read()
```

Comment: You're a savior :)

Answer (score 1):

If you like you can try this method

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater

updater = Updater(token='BOT_TOKEN')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
updater.start_polling()
def test(bot, update):
    results = bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Test", reply_markup={"keyboard":[["Test1"], ["Test2"], ["Test3"], ["Test4"]})
    print results
dispatcher.addTelegramCommandHandler('test', test)
```

This import makes things a lot more short, I just started using it today [python-telegram-bot 3.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-telegram-bot/3.4)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will work:

```
reply_markup = {
    "keyboard": [[{"text":"1"}], [{"text":"2"}]], 
    "resize_keyboard": True, 
    "one_time_keyboard": True
}
```