# how to create keyboard in bot telegram

Tags: keyboard, telegram-bot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6x2A.png)

help me to create keyboard (yes/no) for telegramBot (php)

Comment: SO is not a place to ask people to write your code! What have you done till now your self? Please read these two articles from help center: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099087/telegram-bot-custom-keyboard-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but the tricky part is usually the keyboard part which is an array of arrays. Call [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sendmessage) and pass something like the following json:

```
{
  chat_id: 12345678,
  text: "Hello, do you like ice cream?",
  reply_markup: {
    keyboard: [
      [{text: "Yes"}],
      [{text: "No"}]
    ]
  }
}
```

Replace 12345678 with your chat id.

Answer (score 0):

First get updates and save them into `$update` then for `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` use this method :

```
    if ($update->message->text == '/start') {
    $name = $update->message->chat->first_name;
    bot('sendMessage',[
      'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
      'text'=>'Your Test',
      'resize_keyboard'=>true,
      'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
          'keyboard'=>[
            [
                ['text'=>'Num1'],['text'=>'Num2']
            ],
            [
                ['text'=>'Num2']
            ],
          ]
      ])
    ]);
  }
```

and for inline keyboard you should use this method to send :

```
      'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
          'inline_keyboard'=>[
            [
                ['text'=>'Num1'],['text'=>'Num2']
            ],
            [
                ['text'=>'Num3']
            ],
          ]
      ])
    ]);
  }
```

remember that bot function has 2 parameter that use curl for send and receive datas to telegram api.